# EC2 Launch Failure On Private Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have purchased reserved instance hours and I am unable to launch a reserved instance in my private subnet. The only message I am getting is

```
Launch Failed
The requested configuration is currently not supported. Please check the documentation for supported configurations.
```

How do I troubleshoot this? The message is unhelpful.

```
What I have done:
1. Created two subnets. One public (10.0.0.0/25) and one private (10.0.1.0/25).
2. Assign route tables to each subnet. The public subnet is attached to an Internet Gateway.
```

Here's a review of my instance launch:

```
Instance Type   ECUs        vCPUs   Memory (GiB)    Instance Storage (GB)   EBS-Optimized Available Network Performance
t2.small        Variable    1       2               EBS only                -                       Low to Moderate


Security Group ID         Name               Description
sg-xxxxxxxe               xxxx-private-1a   xxxx-private-1a


All selected security groups inbound rules
Type    Protocol  Port Range    Source  
SSH     TCP       22            0.0.0.0/0


Number of instances    1                             Purchasing option On demand
Network                 vpc-6e385e0a
Subnet                  subnet-98b5e2ee
EBS-optimized           No
Monitoring              No
Termination protection  No
Shutdown behavior       Stop
IAM role                None
Tenancy                 dedicated
Host ID                 
Affinity                Off
Kernel ID               Use default
RAM disk ID             Use default
User data
Assign Public IP        No
Assign IPv6 IP          Use subnet setting (Disable)
Network interfaces

Device    Network Interface        Subnet           Primary IP    Secondary IP Addresses
eth0      New network interface    subnet-98b5e2ee  10.0.1.5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Tenancy                 dedicated
```

Dont choose that. Thats for dedicated hosts. The error is thrown because t2 type instances are not available on dedicated hosts. But you write you have an reserved instance (RI). So you dont want to launch with tenancy dedicated.

Comment: In addition, there is no way to "launch reserved instance".  Reserved instance is just automatic billing allocation. :-)

Comment: Thanks at0mzk, that helps :). I hope the launch error message can be improved. It is vague.